# Mashiach or Moshiach?

Tags: names, messiah

I have seen the word Mashiach spelled with an “o” and sometimes with an “a”.

Is there are a difference? Does it matter?

Comment: Boruch or Baruch? Yisroel or Yisrael

Answer (score 5):

As the comments stated above, the Hebrew vowel after the m is a "kamatz." Some pronounce it closer to "ah", some closer to "o" (actually, more like "uh"). That's all.

(Go into a Jewish bookstore and you'll see keychains with various Jewish names on them. Usually mine is spelled "Sholom" not "Shalom." Same thing.)